# Android Studio Code Completion with Kotlin/Firebase - Misbehaving badly

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

UPDATE: This bug appears always when I'm writing a lambda inside a method of a class, and I refer to a variable of that class. It does not appear when I refer to variables inside the method.

I'm going through a simple guide to Kotlin development with Firebase. But somehow Android Studio has now had its code completion somewhat broken by this.

I have a class called FirestoreUtil in which I have `private val currentUserDocRef`, I cannot get code completion to work properly even when writing within that class.

This problems applies to all classes I write in this project.

I'd start typing 'currentUs' etc... see it suggest the variable and its type. I select it, but instead of just writing

currentUserDocRef

it instead pumps out

com.leonhardprintz.firemessage.utils.FirestoreUtil.currentUserDocRef

It does this consistently, when trying to get completetion for variables I've written myself. External libraries load just fine.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Here are the contents of my gradle files

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    ext.anko_version = '0.10.5'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle- plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
       // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.leonhardprintz.firemessage"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    //support
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    //firebase-ui
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.0.1'
    //glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    //groupie
    implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.0.3'
    implementation 'com.xwray:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:2.0.3'
    //anko
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-coroutines:$anko_version"
    //test
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

    kotlin {
        experimental {
            coroutines "enable"
        }
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Update, I find that it works fine after I build the class. Is that a thing I need to do. Build the project each time I had a variable?

Comment: Scratch that, bug is still there.

Answer (score 1):

I experience the same thing. And it's a bug in Android Studio Kotlin plugin. It won't affect your code, just remove the unnecessary words.

It is annoying indeed, and even now it happen some times. So let's just wait until somebody fix that.

Comment: The bug appears to happen when you're writing a lambda inside a method of a class, and you're referring to a private variable of that class.